# Verb used with the word "dumbbell"

Tags: word-choice

I wonder what verb should be used with the word "dumbbell".
Some sources suggest the verb "to lift".
But my point is "lifting and lowering a dumbbell repeatedly as an exercise". It seems to me that "lifting a dumbbell" means "lifting it for once, not repeatedly lifting and lowering it", like when weightlifters lift weights.

It seems like that English doesn't use a well-established verb for this concept.
Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: to lift weights, to lift dumbbells. There is no other verb.

Comment: Often a more specific verb is used for particular exercises: "**curl** a dumbell" or "**press** a dumbell".  But just like with "lift", only the positive motion is specified and the negative (and the repetition) is implied.

Comment: Or *exercise/work out with dumbbells* What goes up must come down.

Comment: Colloquially, it's "pump iron", even when you're not pumping, and it's not iron.

Comment: *"It seems like that English doesn't use a well-established verb for this concept."* - Yes it does, and that verb is "lift". The word "weightlifter" is very well established, so why would you think that what a weightlifter does is not "lifting"?

Comment: We have adverbs for this. *Lift the dumbbell twenty times...*

Comment: I think the problem here is not so much the word *lift*, but the scope of the "and" and/or the "repeatedly". Maybe "repeatedly lift and lower" is more to your liking?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Lift" really is right.  It's what we generally do with weights, even though lowering under control is an important part of the exercise.  Used alone, "lift" implies a number of reps and even sets suitable for the activity (which can vary, a 1-rep max weight might be more common with barbells, but makes sense here).

In fact, "lift" can be used in context without an object, as in ["do you even lift"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/do-you-even-lift).

If you were lifting a dumbbell to carry it back to the rack, you'd probably use "pick up" instead of "lift".  Other verbs may be used for specific movements , like "curl", "press", or even ["row"](https://www.coachmag.co.uk/dumbbell-exercises/7380/how-to-do-the-one-arm-dumbbell-row) (rare, but used as a verb towards the end of that link).

Answer (score 4):

### “to train with ~”

It is true that many activities that use dumbbells are not strictly “lifting”, so if you want to be more general, and say simply that you are using dumbbells in a variety of physical activities, you can say:

- I **train with** dumbbells
- I **work out with** dumbbells

The verbs here are “to train”, and “to work out”.

- **[to train](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/train)** (v): 26. undertake a course of exercise and diet in order to reach or maintain a high level of physical fitness.
- **[to work out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/work-out)** (v) to exercise in order to improve the strength or appearance of your body

Both of these are intransitive (i.e., they take no object).

### “to lift”

But, if you want a transitive verb, then the best verb is indeed “to lift”

In English, the activity of using weights for muscle training is most commonly known as **weightlifting**, or sometimes just “lifting weights”. As a result, if you say “I lift dumbbells”, people will understand your meaning.

##### Avoid specialized terms for general writing

Within the fitness world, the act of lifting and lowering a weight to build muscle could be called “pressing” (raising up and down) or “curling” (bending at the elbow), depending on how you are using the weight, but I would not recommend these words because they are specialist terms, and would not be widely known to people who are not interested in weight-training. (Particularly “to press” is a verb which has many other meanings in English)

Comment: curl  is not a specialist term. People know what an arm curl is in an exercise class. There are also leg curls. How do you train with a dumbbell without lifting it? Swing it?

Comment: @Lambie you could, though more often you'd [swing a kettlebell](https://www.coachmag.co.uk/kettlebell-exercises/1730/how-to-do-a-kettlebell-swing)

Comment: Ok, but you see my point, I guess.

Comment: “to curl” _is_ a specialist term.  In the context of an exercise class, it has a known meaning, but if I ask someone who has never been to a gym to “curl that weight”, they will have no idea what I’m saying. 

The point I’m making there is that the OP should be careful about looking for a “perfect fit” verb, because that answer may not be the one that has meaning to the greatest number of readers.  I always try to use the most general, widely-understood terms when I do not know the context or audience of the discussion.

Comment: Confirming, as someone who doesn't go to the gym, if someone said to."curl a weight" Id have 2 mental images, both wildly wrong: 1) curling, they want me to throw it at ground level towards some object? 2) move it in a circle somehow, like a pendulum bob moving in a horizontal circle. Which also makes no sense. I'd look blankly and say "What?" -- and I'd expect I had misheard the key word of the request. Lift would be the main term that I had a reference for. If it needed a specialist term - which does add realism - I'd expect that term somehow introduced as part of the narrative.

Comment: @Lambie I do, I just couldn't resist the unlucky counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

If the context implies that the activity persisted over a time interval, then just “lift(ed)” conveys the repetitive nature just fine.  “He spent thirty minutes lifting dumbbells.”

Incorporating  “repetitions”, often shortened to “reps” along with do/did might be useful if you want to explicitly convey the repetitive nature of the activity.  A group of reps comprise a set; there are typically short rests between sets.  “He did a set of reps with some dumbbells.”

Answer (score 0):

Exercise is the word.

DjinTonic had it right. *Exercise* is the unambiguous word describing anything you can do with a dumbbell to use as it was designed to be used. This includes lifting, lowering and swinging. Anything to take advantage of its weight.